# Windows Server 2008 R2 - Copying and pasting a non existing dll

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dll

Is it safe to copy/replace the "`PeerDistSh.dll`" in a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard?
The inexitence of this file seams to not let Windows Update actually update Windows.

After running a `SFC /SCANNOW`, I realise that this tool was not able to succesfully repair the corrupted files... :

```
FINDSTR /C:"[SR]" %WINDIR%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log

2014-07-23 10:11:01, Info                  CSI    00000344 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:28{14}]"PeerDistSh.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-PeerDist-Common, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-07-23 10:11:02, Info                  CSI    00000345 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:28{14}]"PeerDistSh.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-PeerDist-Common, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-07-23 10:14:56, Info                  CSI    000004fe [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:28{14}]"PeerDistSh.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-PeerDist-Common, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-07-23 10:14:56, Info                  CSI    000004ff [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:28{14}]"PeerDistSh.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-PeerDist-Common, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
```

I know I could do something like this, but the files does not exist on the system:

```
TAKEOWN /F C:\Windows\System32\PeerDistSh.dll
ICACLS C:\Windows\System32\PeerDistSh.dll /GRANT Administrators:F
COPY K:\tmp\PeerDistSh.dll C:\Windows\System32\PeerDistSh.dll
```

Is simply copying and pasting the dll from a healty environment a safe solution?

Answer (score 1):

Should be fine, except you should force it into the SFC repository (WinSxS) and then let SFC put it back where it should go (the "file not found" error is SFC telling you it can't find the known-good copy in the repository when trying to replace the one missing from System32).

Comment: Might help if you tell him how to do that ;-)

Comment: @Ramhound I'd explain it but he already showed how to do It (basically), he just used the wrong folder. ;)  I see your point though..

Comment: Took me a minute to realize what that last command was doing.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'm not sure what I have to do. Where exactly am I supposed to copy the dll? Witch folder in "C:\Windows\WinSxS"?

Comment: @Ramhound What command is not clear? I use which wrong folder?

Comment: @user351296 - **Nothing** I didn't fully read the command you issued.